# DaggerAppComponent doesn't generate by dagger plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I was developing an app where I'm using dagger to inject my dependencies, and I get into the trubble when I try configure my Application class:

I have this:

Application .kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application(){
    private lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = initDagger()
    }

    private fun initDagger() = DaggerAppComponent.Builder.build()
}
```

So my only module is AppModule which is this:

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    //If it needed add interceptor in the instance of httpClient above.
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideCodigoQRODeBarrasApi(): CodigoQRODeBarrasApi {
    return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(CodigoQRODeBarrasApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirmaApi(): FirmaApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(FirmaApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideImpresoraApi(): ImpresoraApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(ImpresoraApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLecturaDeTarjetasApi(): LecturaDeTarjetasApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(LecturaDeTarjetasApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMiFareApi(): MiFareApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(MiFareApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePINPADApi(): PINPADApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(PINPADApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTransaccinApi(): TransaccinApi {
        return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(TransaccinApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

And my AppComponent class:

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
    }
}
```

regarding build.grale configuration is the following:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    namespace 'es.paytef.hioposconnector'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.paytef.hioposconnector"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    kapt{
        generateStubs = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    // Librerías agregadas
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.20"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2")

    // retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1"

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40"
    //Singleton and Inject annotation
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03"

    //hilt libraries for custom Component.
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.46"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.46"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.46"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.46"
    //apiconnection
    implementation project(path: ':apiconnection')
}
```

And project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.46"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So, what I'm missing here??

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you register your application class in manifest?

Comment: Yes, and still doesn't generate the class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mix Hilt and Dagger in a single implementation.

If you intend to use Hilt for your project, you don't need to manually create Components manually. Instead, you have several base components like `SingletonComponent`, `ActivityComponent` etc.

And you have to use `@InstallIn(Component::class.java)` annotation for your module to install its dependencies in this component. So that's why you don't need to create your own components.

In your implementation you need to remove all Dagger-related things, and then you can just use your dependencies like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application(){
  @Inject
  lateinit var somePropertyFromSingletonComponent: SomeProperty

  ....     
  ....     
}
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#generated-components) again and fix the code based on documentation.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your answer, but I had understood, I have to init the plugin in my Aplication class. Could you be able to bring me some example of how to do that developing your current answer?

Comment: No, you only need to add plugin in build.gradle what you've done already. And mark your application with `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation (you've done it too) as well as your Fragments and Activities with `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation. Check out the link I've attached please, here are all steps that you have to do, and nothing else.